# c# textbox not displaying all contents

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I want to have a textbox that **displays the word Seq** (which is a column name), then lists values from mylist underneath it. So far, the values from the list show up **but the word Seq doesn't**

```
  private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              if (seq1) 
              {
                  textBox1.Text = " Seq"; // This guy doesn't showup in the textbox
                  foreach (object o in SeqIrregularities)
                  {
                      textBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, SeqIrregularities);
                  }
              }

          }
```

Comment: Probably because you immediately overwrite it in your foreach?

Comment: You can quickly fix this using `textBox1.Text +=` instead of `=` inside the foreach loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're reassigning the value of `textBox1.Text` to your list of values, rather than appending the list of values to the textbox contents.

Try this:

```
 textBox1.Text = " Seq"; // This guy doesn't showup in the textbox
 textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + String.Join(Environment.NewLine, SeqIrregularities);
```

You also don't need to loop through your irregularities if what you're doing is creating a concatenated string of them.

Another way to do it (which may be clearer):

```
string irregularities = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, SeqIrregularities);
string displayString = " Seq" + Environment.NewLine + irregularities;
textBox1.Text = displayString;
```

Comment: You'd also need to add a line break after 'Seq' as that is what the original poster wanted.

Comment: Also, how do I add a new line to the textbox? is it environment.newline ?

I want Seq to be displayed then on the followingline, the list values.

textBox1.Text = "Seq" ... but how would I add a new line  below it?

Comment: @AnnL. I don't know the exact syntax.
textBox1.Text.Environment.Newline = "Seq"?

Comment: @user7068  `Environment.NewLine` represents a line break string, so, to add it after "Seq", you would just use `textBox1.Text = " Seq" + Environment.NewLine;`.  Just add it (using the concatenation `+` operator) to whatever you want before the new line.

Comment: @user7068 I've added another example to my answer.  This shows how to use `Environment.NewLine` and how to build a string from shorter strings.

Answer (score 2):

change your code to this:

```
  private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              if (seq1) 
              {
                  textBox1.Text = " Seq"; // This guy doesn't showup in the textbox
                  foreach (object o in SeqIrregularities)
                  {
                      textBox1.Text += String.Join(Environment.NewLine, SeqIrregularities);
                  }
              }

          }
```

You were overwriting your text in each iteration of your foreach-statement. You have to use `+=` instead of `=` in your foreach-statement.